# Creating JSON from a table in jpg or gif image

Tags: javascript, php, json

Is there a Javascript and/or a PHP library (or a simple method) to generate a JSON object from a jpg, png or a gif image containing a table with data?

Let's say we have a compressed jpg like this:
[image]

And we have to create an array of objects like this:

```
{
    "col1": "sdfdsf",
    "col2": "sdfksdf",
    "col3": ["sddsf", "dsdd"],
    "col4": "sdop8993"
}
```

Comment: No, there's no simple method for image recognition.

Comment: if you have such a image why don't you ask its creator for the raw data?

Comment: Are you planning on using a recognition library or a magician?

Comment: No, there are OCR libraries, but thats only a part of the problem. How much data are you talking about

Comment: @Steve Not really much. I just want to read data from tables scanned from old books.

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski Idk. Which one would be easier?

Comment: I dont know any magicians, so i would have to suggest the latter: http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/ i have not used this (but have some experiance with a c# wrapper of the original c version), but getting this to work is going to be a big project. Unless you are talking lots of data its going to be far cheaper to use human input

Comment: This is very tough. I tried your sample image in here: http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/ and it didnt go well at all. I think the table structure makes it very hard for the ocr.

Comment: @FreemanLambda yes there would need to be preprocessing, but thats relatively simple giving the clearly delineated cells in this specific example. With no idea what kind of variations the op has in the images and how much time they have to spend, i dont know if its feasible or not

Comment: Either way, far to large an issue for a SO answer

Comment: Writing the code that recognises each cell should not be that difficult.  Then you extract each cell out as a smaller image and carry out OCR on the cell image instead of the whole image.